# trying to connect to pgsql in qt driver not loaded

Tags: postgresql, qt

I have windows 10, qt version is 4.14.1 postgres version is 13.3 (most recent as of 7/23/21. When I run the following code below in qt it gives me the following error.

"Driver not loaded Driver not loaded"

("QSQLITE", "QMYSQL", "QMYSQL3", "QODBC", "QODBC3", "QPSQL", "QPSQL7")

I have tried to place dll files into areas like the person in the following youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qeErME39zvw as this worked when I was trying to set up MySQL on qt

```
QSqlDatabase db2 = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
    db2.setHostName("127.0.0.1");
          db2.setUserName("test");
          db2.setPassword("test");
          db2.setDatabaseName("test");
          if (db2.open())
          {
            qDebug() << "\n\n\n database connected successfully\n\n\n";
          }
          else
          {
            qDebug() << "\n\n\n database connection go poop \n\n" << db2.lastError().text() << " \n ";
            qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
          }
          qDebug() << QSqlDatabase::drivers();
          db2.close();
        return 0;
```

Comment: Qt does not come standard with the dll plugin for postgres. Did you build it?

Comment: ***qt version is 4.15.1*** I think that is your Qt-Creator version not your Qt version.

Comment: it should have been 4.14.1. That is what it shows in the file explorer, I just updated the post to reflect that. I am also using this qt documentation here to do the build as you brought up as it seems I may not have done it correctly. https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html I am now having an issue where when trying to use nmake it does not recognize it so I will continue to update later.

Comment: Not recognizing `nmake` likely means you are building for mscv and that you are not running from a Visual Studio developer command prompt.